# How to boost ADB install speed?

Tags: android, adb

I'm installing attempting to install an app on a physical device over Wifi and it takes forever. My average install speed is 85KB/s, which is unreasonably slow. Is there a way to boost the install speed?

Comment: What kind of data rates do you see in other transfers over that wifi network?  Are you and all your neighbors unknowingly shouting each other down in a fight over the same channel spectrum?

Comment: Peak data rate for download is 3MB/s. According to speedtest, my download is 68Mbps and upload is 27Mbps. As a side note, install via USB is 400kbps.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it's not about wi-fi or router, believe me! It has something to do with ADB/Android. Debugging iOS apps on iPhone/iPad over WiFi with Xcode (on macOS) works great and very fast.

Comment: Did you find a solution? it is really "unreasonably" slow. Debugging iOS apps on iPhone/iPad over WiFi with Xcode (on macOS) works great and very fast.

Answer (score -1):

The install speed may be limited by your device's write speed to the filesystem. How fast is it over USB?

Comment: what about AVD? it's slow on the emulator, too.

Comment: __device's write speed to the filesystem.__ - doesn't make sense! it works much faster over USB